# Cordova webview with Android Studio (file:///android_asserts/www/index.html not found)

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I'm trying to implement a Cordova webview in a native Android application. Seems to work fine, the only problem is that the webview keeps returning this error :

> File:///android_asset/www/index.html could not be loaded because
>   ::net ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I'm following this procedure : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html

But where to put the assets/www folder is not clear.. I have it in app/src/ currently and it doesn't work.

I'm using Android Studio with Cordova 3.6.4 library.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, I actually ended up finding the issue myself.

I had to add the assets folder in the build.gradle file :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets {
            srcDir 'src/assets'
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise the index.html file wouldn't be in the .apk after compiling.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

`android_asserts` should be `android_assets`.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I double checked, I misspelt it in my post. Sorry about that, I now corrected the post

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this kind of stuff is where the PhoneGap documentation sucks. It should be in:

```
/platforms/android/assets/www
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work in my case.